# How can i make this mdx query in query designer from ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssms, mdx, query-designer

I have this query which I can execute in SSMS without problem and it shows in descending order.

```
with 
member [Measures].[YTD Sales] as
[Measures].[Invoiced_Am]

select [Measures].[YTD Sales] on columns,
order([01 Customer].[Customer_Nm].[Customer_Nm],
[Measures].[YTD Sales], desc) on rows       

from [VismaBusinessLogistics_cube]
```

How can I order the result in the query designer in SSRS? I cannot create a select - clause there. If I try this with the order function it just show null values in browse window outside where I create the calculated member:

```
order([01 Customer].[Customer_Nm].[Customer_Nm],
[Measures].[YTD Sales], desc)
```

Comment: Well, i went in under the text expression and put "order" function in the complex Select-clause there.... is there no other way i wounder?